# EXPORTING PDF for Print from Indesign - 5 colour print with duotones/monotones, plus CMYK

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, print-production, duotone, color-separation

How to export a 5 color doc to print in pdf export from indesign- . Its CMYK plus one pantone special ink. should i select 'no color conversion' or 'convert to CMYK' and expect my spot color to maintain spot colour status ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to convert to CMYK or not depends on whether you have RGB (or Lab) images and objects that needs to be converted to CMYK. The *Color Conversion* setting **won't** affect spot colors.

Choosing a *Standard* won't convert spot to CMYK either.

What **does** affect spot colors is if you enter *Ink Manager* and tick on *All Spots to Process*.

[image]

But you don't have to just "expect" your spot color to maintain spot color status. Open the exported PDF in Adobe Acrobat and open the *Output Preview* window. The spot color should appear in the list of inks. You can try to toggle it to see if everything is as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you thats so helpful, I never know about the output preview window!I only ever tried to check with the preflight tab, Tracy

Comment: You're welcome! Also have a look at a similar panel in InDesign: *Separations Preview*.

Comment: I do this with extreme regularity... PDF/X-1a is all that's necessary.. Spots are maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "PDF/X-1a:2001" preset and you should be fine.

[image]

Comment: No. That profile will convert other color models to CMYK.

Comment: Actually Rafael, its a clear yes. I just checked to make sure, exporting with the "PDF/X-1a:2001" will keep spot colors in the PDF.

Comment: Nice. I still need to see the spec, to read if it leaves the door open for implementations.